# Rate Widget Search API integration

Tags: search, rating, views

I have a view for search results.

I want to add the "rating" widget, but I cant find a way how to include it in the Search API fields. => The views cant make the relationship.
Is it possible ?

Clarification: 
The view is not the "ordinary" type -> displaying contents, but it is displaying "Search index".
I am able to display fields that are defined by the Search API settings page, but I am unable to add relationships, for example Rate Widget (Vote Results module).

As a solution, I embedded another view as a field. That seems to work, but I am asking if there is another approach out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: you cannot do it in other way, because the view entity is search_api type.